# Site Redirector failing

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, http-redirect

I'm using vitalsource as a redirect source but the issue is that it cant be customized, and can only redirect to a main website. the redirect URL is "https://bc.vitalsource.com/books/9781119493440R150?bc_token=f9984a30-8eae-013c-8d06-0e40f9c629f8&relaunch_vbid=9781119493440R150&course_dash_relaunch=true&dash_student_pay=true", where "9781119493440" is the code I am trying to extract. Right now, it redirects me to a website I am hosting on github at [www.bahaa-aea.github.com/aafaq](http://www.bahaa-aea.github.com/aafaq), but the target https://gust.aafaqeducation.com/ (the numbers i typed)

The number in the redirect link does change based on product, and I would like to know if theres any way to extract it before it redirects me to the github link so I can run custom code to input itinto the website I want.

When It redirects me, the console simply says "ISBN not found in the URL." which is an error code i programmed into it, I think its just trying to read the url that it sends me to rather than the redirect link.

Here is my current JS code:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ISBN Redirect</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  // Get the URL of the previous page
  var referrerUrl = document.referrer;

  // Extract ISBN from the previous page URL
  var isbnMatch = referrerUrl.match(/books\/(\d+)/);
  if (isbnMatch && isbnMatch[1]) {
    var isbn = isbnMatch[1];

    // Construct the new redirected link
    var redirectedLink = "https://gust.aafaqeducation.com/" + isbn;

    // Redirect to the new link
    window.location.href = redirectedLink;
  } else {
    console.error("ISBN not found in the previous page URL.");
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: The code you've provided seems to work as expected with the URL you provided ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqj9wyrz/)). Is there more to this problem that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: No, I've included all the details, vitalsource redirects me but then I'm stuck on that page, you can't access the vitalsource links themselves

Comment: Maybe this is happening because GitHub doesn't have the correct permission to redirect or maybe it's because vitalsource handles the redirect before actually redirecting, where can I check the website's referrer through inspect?

Comment: I can confirm the reffer just says: courses.vitalsource.com

Comment: So `document.referrer` isn't what you're expecting it to be? It's possible that they have the [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header set to [`Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), in which case there's nothing you can do.

Comment: damn I hadn't thought of that you're right, I'll email their dev support and I'll see what happens.